# The module could not be found in react native

Tags: image, react-native

I am new to react native development. I have login screen in that login screen i have logo image, for that i have kept image in resource folder and given that path in code. But getting unable to resolve module.

Why this error coming don't know.

The following is the code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,TouchableOpacity,StatusBar,Image} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Welcome",
    header: null,
  }
  render() {
    // const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar
          barStyle="light-content"
          backgroundColor="#003366"
        />
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>SEDC</Text>
        <View style={styles.user}>
          <Image source={require('./resource/ic_userid.png')}/>
          <TextInput placeholder="Acct No/User Id" style={styles.textInput} underlineColorAndroid={'rgb(0,0,0)'}></TextInput>
        </View>
      <TextInput placeholder="Password" style={styles.textInput} underlineColorAndroid={'rgb(0,0,0)'}></TextInput>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={this.login}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Log In</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  login=()=>{
    // alert("testing......");
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
}
}
```

And the following is the project view in visual studio.

[image]

The code is in Login.js and images are in resource folder. But why the bellow error coming. This is the image code

```
<Image source={require('./resource/ic_userid.png')}/>
```

[image]

But this is the very small question and duplicate, But I don't know why error is coming. So please guide me how to do this.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Image you are hitting is in the wrong directory. You are looking in the /components for a resource directory.

```
<Image source={require('../../resource/ic_userid.png')}/>
```

Remember `./` means current directory.

Your App directory is as so:

```
App.js
  - app
    - components
      - Login
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @JRK

Answer (score 0):

Just try this `<Image source={require('../../resource/ic_userid.png')}/>` instead of using this `<Image source={require('./resource/ic_userid.png')}/>`